# InDesign Script for identifying and replacing images of indd document

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-server

I am using InDesign CS6 server for changing text and images of .indd files.

Though I have got scipt for changing texts but I am not able to change the images of indd document.

Can some one plz help me out with script for identifying all the images used in indd doc and then replacing these images with user selected images.

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a simple layout containing one linked graphic, the following script would relink that graphic to a different file:

```
set replacementFile to "Macintosh HD:Users:me:Desktop:somefile.png"

tell application "InDesignServer"
    tell document 1
        relink link 1 to alias replacementFile
    end tell
end tell
```